# Is there any way to run a terminal command using C# in "Visual studio for Mac"?

Tags: c#

In windows, we can use

```
var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
{
    WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    Arguments = "adb devices"
};
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Similar to that, Do we have anything to execute with terminal in Mac?

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is you have to pass arguments with -c,

```
FileName = "/bin/bash",
Arguments = " -c \"" + argument + " \""
```

Comment: While macOS 11 still ships with bash, it is a very old version. Consider using `zsh` instead.